# How can I change authority runtime on OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event listener?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, openiddict

I am using openid dict client and i want to change authority url runtime using `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`.

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += async context =>
            {
                var authDomain2 = Configuration["Domains:base"];
                context.Options.Authority = $"https://{authDomain2}";
                context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = $"https://{authDomain2}";
            };
```

I added this event to change authority url.
It's updating authority url but still redirecting on old authority url.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L364), you could find the endpoint url will be set before
calling the RedirectToIdentityProvider method. So if you want to modify it at runtime, you could try to use IOptionsMonitor to modify the OpenIDConnectionOption which could achieve your requirement inside the controller or else.

The source codes as below:

```
   private async Task HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        Logger.EnteringOpenIdAuthenticationHandlerHandleUnauthorizedAsync(GetType().FullName!);

        // order for local RedirectUri
        // 1. challenge.Properties.RedirectUri
        // 2. CurrentUri if RedirectUri is not set)
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.RedirectUri))
        {
            properties.RedirectUri = OriginalPathBase + OriginalPath + Request.QueryString;
        }
        Logger.PostAuthenticationLocalRedirect(properties.RedirectUri);

        if (_configuration == null && Options.ConfigurationManager != null)
        {
            _configuration = await Options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(Context.RequestAborted);
        }

        var message = new OpenIdConnectMessage
        {
            ClientId = Options.ClientId,
            EnableTelemetryParameters = !Options.DisableTelemetry,
            IssuerAddress = _configuration?.AuthorizationEndpoint ?? string.Empty,
            RedirectUri = BuildRedirectUri(Options.CallbackPath),
            Resource = Options.Resource,
            ResponseType = Options.ResponseType,
            Prompt = properties.GetParameter<string>(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.Prompt) ?? Options.Prompt,
            Scope = string.Join(" ", properties.GetParameter<ICollection<string>>(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.Scope) ?? Options.Scope),
        };

        // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636
        if (Options.UsePkce && Options.ResponseType == OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[32];
            RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(bytes);
            var codeVerifier = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Encode(bytes);

            // Store this for use during the code redemption. See RunAuthorizationCodeReceivedEventAsync.
            properties.Items.Add(OAuthConstants.CodeVerifierKey, codeVerifier);

            var challengeBytes = SHA256.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
            var codeChallenge = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(challengeBytes);

            message.Parameters.Add(OAuthConstants.CodeChallengeKey, codeChallenge);
            message.Parameters.Add(OAuthConstants.CodeChallengeMethodKey, OAuthConstants.CodeChallengeMethodS256);
        }

        // Add the 'max_age' parameter to the authentication request if MaxAge is not null.
        // See http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest
        var maxAge = properties.GetParameter<TimeSpan?>(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.MaxAge) ?? Options.MaxAge;
        if (maxAge.HasValue)
        {
            message.MaxAge = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor((maxAge.Value).TotalSeconds))
                .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        // Omitting the response_mode parameter when it already corresponds to the default
        // response_mode used for the specified response_type is recommended by the specifications.
        // See http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#ResponseModes
        if (!string.Equals(Options.ResponseType, OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code, StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
            !string.Equals(Options.ResponseMode, OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            message.ResponseMode = Options.ResponseMode;
        }

        if (Options.ProtocolValidator.RequireNonce)
        {
            message.Nonce = Options.ProtocolValidator.GenerateNonce();
            WriteNonceCookie(message.Nonce);
        }

        GenerateCorrelationId(properties);

        var redirectContext = new RedirectContext(Context, Scheme, Options, properties)
        {
            ProtocolMessage = message
        };

        await Events.RedirectToIdentityProvider(redirectContext);
        if (redirectContext.Handled)
        {
            Logger.RedirectToIdentityProviderHandledResponse();
            return;
        }
```